# rename last part of file (using sed)

Tags: bash

I done a "script" to convert audio bitrate:

```
for a in *.mp3 ; do ffmpeg -i "$a" -ar 44100 -ab 80k "$a [80].mp3" ; done
```

obviously new file will be:

```
filename one.mp3 [80].mp3
```

using sed I'd like rename old file with new file like:

```
filename one [80].mp3
```

I see:

```
mv $a $(echo $a | sed 's/.mp3//g')
```

but I've problem with spacefile name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `sed`, `bash` can do it for you. Try this:

```
for a in *.mp3 ; do ffmpeg -i "$a" -ar 44100 -ab 80k "${a%.*} [80].mp3" ; done
```

The `${a%.*}` is `bash` parameter substitution and removes the extension from the filename (basically removes the shortest match from behind).

Read [this](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) for more details.

Alternate method as suggested by [devnull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2235132/devnull) would be to use `basename`.

```
for a in *.mp3 ; do ffmpeg -i "$a" -ar 44100 -ab 80k "$(basename -s.mp3 $a) [80].mp3" ; done
```

From the `man` page:

> DESCRIPTION
>          Print NAME with any leading directory components removed.  **If specified, also remove a trailing SUFFIX.**
>
> ```
>    Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
>
>    -a, --multiple
>           support multiple arguments and treat each as a NAME
>
>    -s, --suffix=SUFFIX
>           remove a trailing SUFFIX
> ```

*Emphasis mine*